# How to make a parent category show every 3 rows of subcategory which sorted by price asc

Tags: template

i have to make a parent category show every 3 rows of subcategory which sorted by price asc, for example

```
cat1 
  cat-A 
  cat-B 
  cat-C
```

if i click cat1 , the page will show

```
  cat-A-product1     cat-A-product2     cat-A-product3
      $1.00                $2.00             $3.00



  cat-B-product1     cat-B-product2     cat-B-product3
      $1.00                $2.00             $3.00



  cat-C-product1     cat-C-product2     cat-C-product3
      $1.00                $2.00             $3.00



  cat-A-product4     cat-A-product5     cat-A-product6
      $4.00                $5.00             $6.00


  cat-B-product4     cat-B-product5     cat-B-product6
      $4.00                $5.00             $6.00
```

What techniques i can achieve this?

----------------------update-----------------------
Added in class

```
public function getTotalPage () {
    $products = $this->getCategory()->getProductCollection();
    return count($products)/9;
}

->setPage($page, $this->getProductLimit());
```

phtml:

```
$subcategories = $this->getSubcategories();

$total = $this->getTotalPage()+1;

for ($i=1; $i<=$total; $i++) {

    if ($subcategories && count($subcategories) > 0 ) : ?>

        <?php foreach ($subcategories as $subcategory) : ?>
        <ul>

            <?php 

            $products = $this->getProducts($subcategory,$i);

            ?>
            <li class="item">
                <?php if ($products && count($products)) : ?>
                    <h2><a href="<?php echo $subcategory->getUrl() ?>"><?php echo $subcategory->getName()?></a></h2>

                    <div class="subcategory-products">
                        <?php foreach ($products as $product) : ?>
                            <div class="item">

                                <a href="<?php echo $product->getProductUrl()?>"><?php echo $product->getName()?></a>
                                <a href="<?php echo $product->getProductUrl()?>">
                                    <img src="<?php echo Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'small_image')->resize(200);?>" alt="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($product->getName())?>" />
                                </a>
                                <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($product);?>
                            </div>
                        <?php endforeach;?>
                    </div>
                <?php endif;?>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <?php endforeach ?>

    <?php endif;

}
```

i have to print all products in the category list, so i added a for loop try to print all pages attach one by one

**$products = $this->getProducts($subcategory,$i);**  not work , but

$products = $this->getProducts($subcategory,1); 
$products = $this->getProducts($subcategory,2);

are ok. i can't getProducts dynamically. Even the $i is changed to 2, the program still print the first page. So if the for loop $i is 2, the program print the first product page twice.

```
--------------solved--------------------
            //$this->_products[$subcategory->getId()] = $products;
        }
        return $products;
```

Comment: Very interesting question. Unfortunately it is too broad to answer !. What did you try ?

Comment: does custom layout update can do this?

Comment: about the update...change this `return count($products/9);` to this `return count($products) / 9;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento offers the possibility to use a static block for a category page. Let's make use of that.
But first you need to create a new module with a block that retrieves the products for the child subcategories of a certain category and a template that displays them.
Let's call the module `Easylife_Catalog`.
You will need the following files.
`app/etc/modules/Easylife_Catalog.xml` - the declaration file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Easylife_Catalog>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <active>true</active>
            <depends>
                <Mage_Catalog />
            </depends>
        </Easylife_Catalog>
    </modules>
</config>
```

`app/code/local/Easylife/Catalog/etc/config.xml` - the configuration file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Easylife_Catalog>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Easylife_Catalog>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <easylife_catalog>
                <class>Easylife_Catalog_Block</class>
            </easylife_catalog>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

`app/code/local/Easylife/Catalog/Block/Category.php` - the block that retrieves the subcategories and products. See the comments in the code.

```
<?php
class Easylife_Catalog_Block_Category extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract
{
    const DEFAULT_PRODUCT_LIMIT = 3;
    protected $_products = array();

    /**
     * get the category id.
     * if one is specified, use that.
     * If not check if you are on a category page
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getCategoryId()
    {
        if (!$this->hasData('category_id')) {
            if ($category = Mage::registry('current_category')) {
                $this->setData('category', $category);
                $this->setData('category_id', $category->getId());
            } else {
                $this->setData('category_id', false);
            }
        }
        return $this->getData('category_id');
    }

    /**
     * get the current category
     * @return Mage_Catalog_Model_Category|bool
     */
    public function getCategory()
    {
        $this->getCategoryId();
        if (!$this->hasData('category')) {
            $categoryId = $this->getCategoryId();
            if ($categoryId) {
                $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
                    ->setStoreId($this->getStoreId())
                    ->load($categoryId);
                if ($category->getId()) {
                    $this->setData('category', $category);
                } else {
                    $this->setData('category', false);
                }
            } else {
                $this->setData('category', false);
            }
        }
        return $this->getData('category');
    }

    /**
     * get the product limit
     * @return int
     */
    public function getProductLimit()
    {
        return $this->getDataSetDefault('product_limit', self::DEFAULT_PRODUCT_LIMIT);
    }

    /**
     * get the current category subcategories
     * @return Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Category_Collection|bool
     */
    public function getSubcategories()
    {
        if (!$this->getCategory()) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!$this->hasData('subcategories')) {
            $subcategories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
                ->setStoreId($this->getStoreId())
                ->getCollection()
                ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                ->addAttributeToFilter('parent_id', $this->getCategory()->getId())//only children of the current category
                ->addAttributeToFilter('is_active', 1) //only active categories
                ->addAttributeToSort('position', 'ASC');
            $this->setData('subcategories', $subcategories);
        }
        return $this->getData('subcategories');
    }

    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public function getStoreId()
    {
        return Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
    }

    /**
     * if there is no current category, render nothing
     * @return string
     */
    protected function _toHtml()
    {
        if (!$this->getCategory()) {
            return '';
        }
        return parent::_toHtml();
    }

    /**
     * get the products for a subcategory
     * @param Mage_Catalog_Model_Category $subcategory
     * @return Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection
     */
    public function getProducts(Mage_Catalog_Model_Category $subcategory)
    {
        if (!isset($this->_products[$subcategory->getId()])) {
            $products = $subcategory->getProductCollection()
                ->addAttributeToSelect(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/config')->getProductAttributes())
                ->addMinimalPrice()
                ->addFinalPrice()
                ->addTaxPercents()
                ->addUrlRewrite($subcategory->getId())
                ->addAttributeToSort('price', 'ASC')
                ->setPage(1, $this->getProductLimit());
            $this->_products[$subcategory->getId()] = $products;
        }
        return $this->_products[$subcategory->getId()];
    }
}
```

`app/design/frontend/base/default/template/easylife_catalog/category.phtml` - the template for rendering the products - you may need to change the markup or add styles.

```
<?php
/** @var Easylife_Catalog_Block_Category $this */
$subcategories = $this->getSubcategories();
if ($subcategories && count($subcategories) > 0 ) : ?>
    <?php foreach ($subcategories as $subcategory) : ?>
        <div class="subcategory">
            <?php $products = $this->getProducts($subcategory);?>
            <?php if ($products && count($products)) : ?>
                <h2><a href="<?php echo $subcategory->getUrl() ?>"><?php echo $subcategory->getName()?></a></h2>    
                <div class="subcategory-products">
                    <?php foreach ($products as $product) : ?>
                        <div class="item">
                            <a href="<?php echo $product->getProductUrl()?>"><?php echo $product->getName()?></a>
                            <a href="<?php echo $product->getProductUrl()?>">
                                <img src="<?php echo Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'small_image')->resize(200);?>" alt="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($product->getName())?>" />
                            </a>
                            <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($product);?>
                        </div>
                    <?php endforeach;?>
                </div>
            <?php endif;?>
        </div>
    <?php endforeach ?>
<?php endif;
```

Clear the cache.

Now you need to create a static block.
Go to `CMS->Static Blocks->Add New Block`.
Fill in the fields:

Block Title : Subcategories with products
Block Identifier: subcategories
Store View: All
Status: Enabled
Content:  `{{block type="easylife_catalog/category" template="easylife_catalog/category.phtml"}}`

Save it.
Now edit the category you want to display subcategory products, go to the `Display Settings` tab and select for `Display Mode`: `Static  Block` or `Static Block and products`.
And for the `CMS Block` select the block you just created earlier (Subcategories with products).
Save and enjoy.

Side note.
Because of the way the block is built you can pass as parameter the number of products to be rendered for each subcategory like this:

```
{{block type="easylife_catalog/category" template="easylife_catalog/category.phtml" product_limit="5"}}
```

This will make it render 5 products for each subcategory. If nothing is specified it defaults to 3 products.

If you want you can use this block in a cms page but you have to specify a category id:

```
{{block type="easylife_catalog/category" template="easylife_catalog/category.phtml" category_id="10"}}
```

This way it will render all the subcategories of the category with the id 10.
If you don't specify a category id it will check if you are on a category page and use that one.

Comment: i'm testing your answer, <?php $products = $this->getProducts($subcategory);?> shoud go before ($products && count($products)) ? right?

Comment: @hkinterview. Right. Sorry for that. Copy / paste error. I fixed it. Let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to customize particular category, then first of all you need to start customization from a layout update. For each category, magento will generate a unique layout handle `CATEGORY_{ID}`. For example, suppose category id of parent category in question be 4, then you can put your customization like this.

```
<CATEGORY_4>
  <!-- custom customization comes here -->
</CATEGORY_4>
```

But in your case, I dont think this is necessary. You need to customize the product collection method sorting method which magento uses in category pages for this particular category. You can achieve this by developing a custom module and observing or rewriting a core class.